# How to estimate precision on a prediction for a GLMM for an unobserved level of a random effect

Tags: lme4-nlme, glmm, prediction-interval

I am modelling values that are rates, strictly positive, using a Gamma GLM and or GLMM (here using `glmer` in `lme4`) to do so, with a log link. Assume that I have a GLMM model that is of the form

`glmer(rate~(1|location)+(1|year),data=data,family=Gamma(link="log"))`

where both factors , location and year are random effects. The best estimate for the prediction of the mean at a new site and new year, that were both unobserved, is given by the overall mean of the model, so equal to exp(intercept). The summary of the model returns also a standard error, but  that would be the standard error for the overall mean. How can one estimate the precision of a prediction for the mean at a new, unobserved, year-location combination? Is this available via `glmer`?
A possible intuitive approach might be via a parametric bootstapp, resampling values from the distribution of the overall mean (intercept with corresponding precision), and then add sampled values from the variability associated with each of the random effects, and compute the variability of the resulting estimates of means for unobserved combinations of random effects. Is that a sensible thing to do? If not, can someone point me to a place that might describe how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr** A parametric bootstrap (#3 below), or a cheesy parametric bootstrap (#2 below), are probably the most straightforward approaches.

The components of uncertainty are (1) the sampling variance of the fixed effect components $\mathbf V$ (for a fixed-effect model matrix $\mathbf X$, the corresponding variances of the predictions are $\textrm{Diag}(\mathbf X \mathbf V \mathbf X^\top))$; (2) the variances of the random effects (for previously unmeasured levels, if $\boldsymbol \Sigma$ is the covariance matrix of the random effects, then $\textrm{Diag}(\mathbf Z \boldsymbol \Sigma \mathbf Z^\top)$ are the corresponding variances of the random-effects components of the prediction. Combining these components is easy, because they're Gaussian.

Notes so far:

- you can construct $\mathbf X$ with `model.matrix()`; you could use `lFormula()` and extract the `reTrms$Zt` component to get $\mathbf Z^\top$ (or, see the machinery in `vignette("lmer", package = "lme4")` and use `model.matrix()` + `Matrix::fac2sparse` + `Matrix::KhatriRao` to make your own).  $\mathbf V$ comes from `vcov()`; $\boldsymbol \Sigma$ is `crossprod(getME(., "Lambda"))`.

Once you go back from the link to the response scale (exponentiating the random effects, which are on the log scale) we end up with a log-Normal with the specified mean and variance.

The hard part is combining the Gamma distribution. What we have now is a generalized logNormal-Gamma distribution (ugh).

1. If you just wanted the variance (and were prepared, e.g., to construct confidence intervals based on a Gaussian distribution), you could get the variance of the generalized distribution by combining the Gamma and log-Normal variance (the formula for the variance of a generalized distribution in terms of the mean and variance of its components can be derived from generating functions, and is in Pielou's *Mathematical Ecology* book, which I don't have with me right now ... it may appear elsewhere on the web but I couldn't find it in a quick search).
2. The next better approach, which would be pretty quick: draw MVN samples (using `MASS::mvrnorm` or one of the other alternatives in the R ecosystem) from the distribution with the combined FE sampling variance + RE variance, exponentiate them, and draw Gamma samples based on those mean values. This is basically the method described in section 7.5.3 of Bolker (2008), which Lande et al. 2003 call "population prediction intervals".  This is pretty good, but ignores uncertainty in the RE covariance matrix.  You might be able to implement this with `simulate()` —
3. "True" parametric bootstrapping would simulate, re-estimate parameters, and then do the computation above including the RE variance but *not* the FE sampling variance (that part would be handled by the sampling/re-fitting).
4. Or you could go all the way Bayesian ...

These four choices are essentially ordered by computational effort (the actual Bayesian computation might not be slower than the parametric bootstrap, but might take more effort to set up).

---

Second thoughts after starting an implementation. Not sure that we actually want $\boldsymbol \Sigma$ from the model, which is the covariance matrix of the random effects in the *fitted* model. Instead, we want to create a new standalone model block and push the relevant elements of the `theta` vector into it ...

Comment: Very useful. To clarify the number of options provided: You start by suggesting two options as the most straightforward, ("parametric bootstrap, or a cheesy parametric bootstrap"), but you actually describe four: 1. full but tortuous & dangerous approach, 2.  quick non-parametric approach, 3. true parametric approach, and 4. a comment about a full Bayesian approach (here I miss the coment re "If you wanted to compute just variances (and rely on approximate Normality)"). I will try 3. the "true" parametric bootstrapp approach first. Can you comment on what might be the advantage of 1. over 3.?

Comment: I have created a git repos https://github.com/TiagoAMarques/Report4BB where I implemented in section 5 "almost" your suggestions #2 and #3, comparing the results (interesting comparison, see last fig in the html). The why "almost" here is a topic I would love to get your insights over. File "SpermWhaleCueRatesSuppPub1.html" is a dynamic report that shows the analysis, the data is also on the repos. Feedback would be appreciated on the point after "and would love some additional insight from BB" :) Hope I'm not breaking any stack exchange rules with this behaviour.